# How make concatenation two css files in one only with missing code?

Tags: concatenation

I work in team, with a developer, we write markup. My question is how we can make concatenation our two css files in one and do it only with missing code, P.S. We both work in one project.

Comment: It is better to add what you have done so for and where you have stuck.

Comment: I am not stuck, I try understand how I can make this easely, maybe exist a plagin for package manager.